# reversing an array using methods and MessageBox.show

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I'm having issue with the following code:

```
public int ReverseArray(int[] rArray)
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        Array.Reverse(array);
        foreach (int value in array)
        {
            return (value);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void reverseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] input = new int[10]; 
        int output = ReverseArray(input);
        MessageBox.Show(""+ output);
    }
```

The code is supposed to take the given array (int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };) and reverse it upon a button click; however, when I click on the reverseButton, I only get the number 8 and not the entire array. I'm sure it's the way my reversButton code is written, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
How can I fix my code to where when I click on reverseButton, the entire array will be displayed in reverse order?

Comment: First, I want to make this absolutely clear: I'm not here to insult, I'm here to help. 
Your current code does not make sense. You already know there's a built in method for reversing arrays, why wrap it with your own? Also, if you want to reverse an array, why does your method returns a single int? And why doesn't do anything with the argument you are passing to it? Seems to me like you need to go through the basics of c# before you can actually write code.

Comment: I completely agree, unfortunately, this is an assignment (i know how everyone frowns against posting assignments.) for "Starting out with C#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning whole array back and also not iterating the array result and Array is a collection of items to you need to tell it to get each item one by one and print.

You can do something like following to make it work:

```
public int[] ReverseArray(int[] rArray)
{
        Array.Reverse(array);
        return array;
}
```

and in button click event you can use it:

```
int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
input = ReverseArray(input); 

string items = String.Join(",",input);
MessageBox.Show(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your method `ReverseArray` just returns one value:

```
public int[] ReverseArray(int[] rArray)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    Array.Reverse(array);
    return array;
}
```

To show whole array you can combine it into some string:

```
int[] output = ReverseArray(input);
var message = string.Join(", ", output);
```

And show:

```
MessageBox.Show(message);
```